# Why data changing when I fetch data from MySQL database using angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

1. In MySQL, database data is: `2019-02-01 02:40:16` and when I fetching data to UI page using angular6 that time data showing: `2019-01-31T21:10:16.000+0000`
2. Where null data is therein Database, that time showing: NA

How I correct this problem, please suggest to me.

Comment: Check for handling of timezones in your app and in MySql

Comment: I had a similar problem.This could happen if you're MySQL was setup in a different timezone than you are in.

Answer (score 0):

> In MySQL, database data is: 2019-02-01 02:40:16 and when I fetching
>   data to UI page using angular6 that time data
>   showing:2019-01-31T21:10:16.000+0000

In your server, the date is stocked with the UTC TimeZone, I think.

And in your front side, you are not in this time zone but 6 hour before (Mountain Time (US) MDT UTC-6 ??).

> Where null data is therein Database, that time showing: NA

You have to assure that the data is not null before displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

timezone offset of 5:30 hrs is being subtracted to match your timezone as your MySQL stores value in a different timezone.